# jquery scrolls to same spot on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have an html image map and depending on where you click, will scroll to different spots on the page. I have multiple divs that I can't give id's so I created divs above each one that has an id so I can scroll to it.

```
<div id="Nashville-TN"></div>
<div class="speaking-date">...</div>
<div id="SanAntonio-TX"></div>
<div class="speaking-date">...</div>
```

and so on. This is what I use to scroll:

```
function FindPlace(place){
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j('html,body').animate({
scrollTop: $j("#"+place).position().top    
            }, 2000);                        
}
```

I'm using noConflict because it's in WordPress. Variable "place" is a string of wherever they clicked i.e. Nashville-TN. It's defined in the image map. FindPlace is called using onclick in the html image map. Here's a snippet of the html map:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-9363 nopin" 
src="linkToPicture.png" alt="Alt text here" usemap="#usmap-withstars-011.png" 
width="979" height="688" border="0" /> 
<map id="ImageMapsCom-usmap-withstars-011.png" name="usmap-withstars-011.png">
    <area style="outline: none;" title="Nashville, TN September 24, 2015" alt="" coords="626,398,650,419" shape="rect" href="#September24.2015" target="_self" onclick="FindPlace('Nashville-TN')"/> 
    <area style="outline: none;" title="San Antonio, TX September 25, 2015" alt="" coords="444,497,468,518" shape="rect" href="#September25.2015" target="_self" onclick="FindPlace('SanAntonio-TX')"/> 
    <area style="outline: none;" title="Image Map" alt="Image Map" coords="977,686,979,688" shape="rect" href="http://www.image-maps.com/index.php?aff=mapped_users_0" /> 
</map>
```

No matter where I click it scrolls to the same spot on the page. Any help or tips is appreciated.

My main problem was that the divs without the ids had a float:left style while the divs I created with the ids didn't. That's why it scrolled to the same spot. I fixed that and it worked.

Comment: Where is the FindPlace method called?

Comment: why are you using `jQuery.noConflict();` ? What libraries are you using ? And where do you define `place` ?

Comment: it's called using html's onclick method

Comment: jQuery is already in "noConflict mode"...You can simply use: `var $j = jQuery;`

Comment: @Dylan, please edit your question and show your full code (including the click handler)

Comment: @rnevius Is that good? I don't want to just dump all my code out because I was told that's bad form.

Comment: @Dylan Do you get the same value for `place`in the debugger when you insert a breakpoint on the `var j =...` line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using [`offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/), which returns the position relative to the `document`:

```js
function FindPlace(place){
    jQuery('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: jQuery("#"+place).offset().top    
    }, 2000);                        
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div onclick="FindPlace('Houston')">Click to Houston</div>
<div onclick="FindPlace('San-Francisco')">Click to San Francisco</div>

<div id="Houston" style="margin: 800px 0;">Houston Target</div>
<div id="San-Francisco" style="margin-bottom: 800px;">San Francisco Target</div>
```

**EDIT:**

Since you're using `area` elements, you can't use the `onclick` attribute. You can, however, set the `href` of these elements, and use a `.click()` event:

```
<area href="#Houston" />
```

...and the script:

```
jQuery('area').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    FindPlace(jQuery(this).attr('href'));
});
```

You'll need to remove the `#` in your `FindPlace` function in order for this second example to work.

Comment: Then the error is somewhere else. I just added an example that shows this should be working.

Comment: Do my divs need to have styles or is it fine to just have the id?

Comment: No, I just added styles so that the example would work properly.

Comment: Do you see a problem with the html image map?

Comment: @Dylan It looks like the `area` tag does not support the `onclick` attribute.  Have you tried using `href` attribute instead?  http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_area.asp

Comment: Rather than using the `onclick` attribute (which `area` doesn't have), you can use the `.click()` method of jQuery, and use the `href`, as @apandit recommended.

Comment: @rnevius Can you show me an example of how this would look?

Comment: @Dylan Did you try my suggestion the way it is presented below?

Comment: Thanks for your advice and help! it was an issue with my divs but your answer was descriptive and helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code to the following.  Note that I have added the `<a>` elements inside the divs and have changes the `href` attributes to match names of the new `<a>` elements.

```
<div id="Nashville-TN"><a name="nashville"></a></div>
<div class="speaking-date">...</div>
<div id="SanAntonio-TX"><a name="sanantonio"></a></div>
<div class="speaking-date">...</div>
```

...

```
<map id="ImageMapsCom-usmap-withstars-011.png" name="usmap-withstars-011.png">
    <area style="outline: none;" title="Nashville, TN September 24, 2015" alt="" coords="626,398,650,419" shape="rect" href="#nashville" target="_self" /> 
    <area style="outline: none;" title="San Antonio, TX September 25, 2015" alt="" coords="444,497,468,518" shape="rect" href="#sanantonio" target="_self" /> 
    <area style="outline: none;" title="Image Map" alt="Image Map" coords="977,686,979,688" shape="rect" href="http://www.image-maps.com/index.php?aff=mapped_users_0" /> 
</map>
```

Comment: @rnevius True! Good call.